# Are all lambdas inside templated lambdas also templated lambdas?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14

Consider this code (which compiles on GCC and MSVC):

```
int main()
{
    auto foo = [](auto p){
        typedef decltype(p) p_t;
        auto bar = [](){
            return static_cast<p_t>(10);
        };
        return bar();
    };

    std::cout << foo(0ull) << std::endl;
}
```

`foo()` is a templated lambda because it has an `auto` parameter.  But for `bar()` to know the type `p_t`, it must somehow be implicitly templated too, which then leads me to the question in the title:

**Are all lambdas inside templated lambdas also templated lambdas?**

If that's the case, then it seems like the number of templates parameters will grow pretty quickly if I have lots of nested lambdas (not necessarily a bad thing, but it comes as a surprise to me).

Comment: It is no more template then a regular class inside a class template. E.g. `template <typename> struct Foo { struct Bar {}; };`.

Comment: @yurikilochek I don't think so. Or at least, not exactly the same. In your case you have a local class of an outer class, therefore accessible from outside or any other point of the class itself. In the case of the lambda, it's a local type as if you define it within a member function, therefore its name is not visible from outside the member body.

Comment: @skypjack aren't lambdas independent from the scope they  were declared?

Comment: @skypjack you just mean that there is simply no way to access the class of the lambda function the way we can do `vector::iterator` right?

Comment: @skypjack accessibility/visibility is orthogonal to templateness.

Comment: @yurikilochek The answer section is below.

Comment: @yurikilochek I mean `template<typename> struct S { struct T {}; };` vs `template<typename> struct S { void operator()() { struct T {}; } };`. You suggested the first case, the second one is probably closer. And in the second case, `T` name isn't available to the outer world. That being said, none of them is exactly the same as if I had used a lambda.

Comment: TIL you can declare a local class in a member function.

Comment: They are temploids, or as the standard calls them, [*templated entities*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#def:templated_entity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can actually say that a lambda is templated. The type of lambda with auto template parameter is not a template at all in the sense it does not match to template template parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

auto foo = [](auto param){};

template <class T>
struct functor_template { 
    void operator()() const { }
};

template <template <class...> class Foo, class... Ts>
void bar(Foo<Ts...>) {
}

int main() {
    //bar(foo); //prog.cc:7:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed
    bar(functor_template<int>{});
}
```

The reason for that is quite simple - only thing that is very close to be called template in such lambdas is their `operator()`.

---

But I think you wanted to ask more if the type of lambda inside the lambda with auto parameter(s) is depended on parameters' types passed to that lambda. The answer is - yes. This can be easily tested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

auto foo = [](auto p){
        static_cast<void>(p);
        typedef decltype(p) p_t;
        auto bar = [](){
            return static_cast<p_t>(10);
        };
        return bar;
    };

int main() {
    static_cast<void>(foo);
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(foo(int{})), decltype(foo(float{}))>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(foo(int{})), decltype(foo(int{}))>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
```